# jQuery Flipclock multiple times on a page with the same class name not working

Tags: jquery, flipclock

I have used [jQuery Flipclock Plugin](http://flipclockjs.com/) to show flipclock. it is working fine when I have used with a class which is just one time in my page. But when I am trying to use the flip clock for multiple times on a page with the same class name it does not work. You can see the [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/NewUserFiddle/r2sw50n7/2/) where I have tried to use it multiple times and its not working. So can someone tell me how to use this plugin multiple times on a page with the same class name?

The code for this flipclock looks like this

```
<div class="clock" style="margin:2em;"></div>
    <div class="message"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var clock;

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var clock;

            clock = $('.clock').FlipClock({
                clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
                autoStart: false,
                callbacks: {
                    stop: function() {
                        $('.message').html('The clock has stopped!')
                    }
                }
            });

            clock.setTime(220880);
            clock.setCountdown(true);
            clock.start();

        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, the plugin is not supporting multiple instances per call(since it is returning a clock instance, it can return only one clock at once).

So the solution is to loop through each element and for each one call the `Flipclock` plugin like

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.clock').each(function () {
        var clock;

        clock = $(this).FlipClock({
            clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
            autoStart: false,
            callbacks: {
                stop: function () {
                    $('.message').html('The clock has stopped!')
                }
            }
        });

        clock.setTime(220880);
        clock.setCountdown(true);
        clock.start();
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jgznschf/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple occurrences of the same class on your DOM jQuery returns an (jquery) array of jquery elements. In order to manipulate each occurence there is a loop method `each()`:

```
$(".clock").each(function(){
    var clock;
    clock = $('.clock').FlipClock({
        clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
        autoStart: false,
        callbacks: {
            stop: function() {
                $('.message').html('The clock has stopped!')
            }
        }
    });
    clock.setTime(220880);
    clock.setCountdown(true);
    clock.start();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the jQuery selector for a class it will only select one element. Best bet is to use jQuerys .each() function to loop through them. Make the variable clock an array and assign each .clock to the array like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var clock = [];
    var i = 0;
    $('.clock').each(function(){
        clock[i] = $(this).FlipClock({
            clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
            autoStart: false,
            callbacks: {
                stop: function() {
                    $('.message').html('The clock has stopped!')
                }
            }
        });
        i++;
    });
    for (var j = 0; j < $(".clock").length; j++) {      
        clock[j].setTime(220880);
        clock[j].setCountdown(true);
        clock[j].start();
    };
});
```

Now if you want to manipulate any of the clocks you can access them via clock[int]. You might want to move the var clock = [] declaration outside of the document ready call to make it available globally.